# Create dataframe column name or list element with a variable

Tags: r, list, dataframe

To create a data.frame or a list I can write

```
data.frame(yo=1:2, wesh=3:4)

  yo wesh
1  1    3
2  2    4

list(yo=1:2, wesh=3:4)

$yo
[1] 1 2

$wesh
[1] 3 4
```

But if I write

```
i <- "yo"
data.frame(i=1:2, wesh=3:4)

   i wesh
1  1    3
2  2    4

list(i=1:2, wesh=3:4)
$i
[1] 1 2

$wesh
[1] 3 4
```

The i doesn't update to "yo" in the output. How to make it possible?

Comment: x <- data.frame(i=1:2, wesh=3:4)

i <- "yo"

library(data.table)

setnames(x, old=c("i"), new=c("yo"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because It is not evaluated when you define it as the name of the variable in `data.frame()`. Try `data.frame(i = i, wesh = 3:4)` to see the difference. However, a workaround can be to use `setNames`, i.e.

```
setNames(data.frame(1:2, 3:4), c(i, 'wesh'))

#same for lists
#setNames(list(1:2, 3:4), c(i, 'wesh'))
```

which gives,

> ```
>    yo wesh
> 1  1    3
> 2  2    4
> ```